# Pandas dividing by occurences in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to divide one column by the amount of occurences of a ticket number in another column.

[image: Some of the input]

While it is not exactly evident here, the Fare is made up of the total amount of passengers sharing a ticket number, and so i would like to divide it to get the individual fare. I expect the output to be the Fare divided by the total number of passengers with the same Ticket number. Whether that is in a new column or the already existing Fare column is secondary. The column where the occurence of values should be counted is 'Ticket', and the 'Fare' column should be divided by the amount of entries under the specific 'Ticket' value.

The full dataset is available here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasciencedojo/datasets/master/titanic.csv

So far i've tried inputting occurences in a dictionary and using the value_counts()-method, but i keep running into an unhashable object-error.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: post a more representative input dataset and the expected output

Comment: What is the amount of occurrences column? Also please provide the data frame and not just a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby_transform` to broadcast the `size` to each row then you can divide the individual `Fare` by the number of the same ticket:

```
# df['NumTickets'] = df.groupby('Ticket').transform('size')  # For demo purpose only
df['FarePerTicket'] = df['Fare'] / df.groupby('Ticket').transform('size')
```

Output:

```
>>> df[['Ticket', 'Fare', 'NumTickets', 'FarePerTicket']]
               Ticket     Fare  NumTickets  FarePerTicket
0           A/5 21171   7.2500           1         7.2500
1            PC 17599  71.2833           1        71.2833
2    STON/O2. 3101282   7.9250           1         7.9250
3              113803  53.1000           2        26.5500  # 2 tickets 113803
4              373450   8.0500           1         8.0500
..                ...      ...         ...            ...
886            211536  13.0000           1        13.0000
887            112053  30.0000           1        30.0000
888        W./C. 6607  23.4500           2        11.7250  # 2 tickets W./C. 6607
889            111369  30.0000           1        30.0000
890            370376   7.7500           1         7.7500
```

Ticket count:

```
>>> df.value_counts('Ticket')
Ticket
1601        7
CA. 2343    7
347082      7
CA 2144     6
347088      6
           ..
345572      1
345364      1
343276      1
343275      1
347464      1
Name: count, Length: 681, dtype: int64
```

Alternative (not recommended):

```
df['Fare'] / df['Ticket'].map(df.value_counts('Ticket'))
```